# Android Video Intent not saving video to desired location

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I have this code:

**(This is code that call the video intent)**

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile()));
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT , 5);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
startActivityForResult(videoIntent, VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

**(Rest of code)**

```
private static final int VIDEO_REQUEST = 2888;

public static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FolderApp");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        //Cant create folder!!
        return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + "_VID_" + timeStamp + ".3gp");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return mediaFile;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //OK!! but not create a video file returned in getOutputMediaFile()
    }
}
```

The video is not saving it to desired location similar thing **I did try with Image capture and it worked**.

Comment: What are you getting back via `getData()` on the `Intent` handed to `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: Because i have read that the getData() works in some phones not in all. In some post from this site (and others) suggest use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. They say that getData() returns null sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The video is not saving it to desired location

There is no requirement that a camera app follow the rules of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` or `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`. Some will honor a specific requested output location. Some will not, and will return where they chose to store the image/video in the `Uri` contained in the result `Intent` delivered on `onActivityResult()`. Some may be completely broken and not tell you anything about where the image/video was stored, even if there was one stored.

> I did try with Image capture and it worked

My guess is that you did not try it on the hundreds of camera applications that come pre-installed on devices or are available on the Play Store, Amazon AppStore for Android, BlackBerry World, the Nokia X Store, the Yandex store, etc.

If you wish to rely upon third-party camera apps, your best course of action is:

- Specify a desired output location
- In `onActivityResult()`, see if the output was written where you requested, and if so, use it
- Otherwise, in `onActivityResult()`, obtain the `Uri` from the `Intent`, and if it is not `null`, use it
- Otherwise, tell the user to download a better camera app, perhaps linking them to one that you know works well with your app

Comment: It may also help to query the MediaStore content provider, if the result is not where you expected to find it.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare! you're right.. what I did is save the uri reference before start recording, and when I got the result Ok, just loaded the info from the uri. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Maybe you can try:

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
```

instead of

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
```

for your video location... but it's just a guess

The way that always works for me:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(data == null) {
        //CANNOT GET URI
        return;
    }

    File source = new File(data.getData().getPath());
    File destination = new File(PATH_TO_YOUR_DESIRE_LOCATION,FILENAME);

    //MOVE FILE
    if(source.renameTo(destination)) {
        //success
    } else {
        //something's wrong
    }
}
```

Also if you set `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` parameter to `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent, then
`getData()` inside `onActivityResult` will always return `null`